# How to check an empty array returned from a function in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I was asked to write a function that accepts a character array, a zero-based start position, and a length.
It should return a character array containing length characters (len) starting with the start character of the input array

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<iterator> 

using namespace std;

char* lengthChar(char c[],int array_len, int start, int len)
{
    char* v = new char[len];
    if(start < 0 || len > array_len || (start + len - 1) >= array_len){
        return NULL;
    }
    if((start + len) == start) 
    {
        return v;
    }

    copy(&c[start], &c[len+start], &v[0]);

    return v;
}
```

My question is when I call my function as

`char* r = lengthChar(t,3, 1, 0);`

Normally based on my implementation, it should return a pointer pointing to an empty array. However, I can't seem to verify this. When I do `if(!r[0])`, it doesn't detect it. I even did

```
char s[] = {};
char* tt = &s[0];
if(r[0] == *tt)
```

Still nothing. The strange thing is when I `cout` the value of r[0], nothing is printed. So I don't know what actually is return. How do I verify that it is empty?

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of arrays.It will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: or even std::array it also exists nowadays. C arrays make your live unnecessarily hard. If I have to use them I always work with the size as a separate parameter.

Comment: If you're using `new[]` you're already missing a large part of what makes modern C++ enjoyable. Make use of Standard Library containers like `std::vector` or `std::array` and don't mess around with manual allocations like this unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: The default initialization for a `char`  is to do nothing. If nothing was expressly written to  `v[0]`, the odds are against `r[0]` being 0. if `r` is `NULL`, that's a different test and `r[0]` would be dereferencing a null pointer. Even [Ol' Hitman Hart knows not to do that.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLHL75H_VEM)

Comment: There is no way in C++ to determine the length of an array from a pointer, of any size. Use a vector instead.

Comment: You are allocating memory with new then returning NULL, leaving memory leaks. So move the allocation down a few lines.

Comment: With an empty array r[0] will be accessing beyond the array. You shouldn't do this. Arrays are not null terminated.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `if(!r[0])` to check if `NULL` was returned.  You want to compare directly to `NULL` using `if(!r)` or `if(r == NULL)`.  This will tell you if the string is empty.  Doing `if(!r[0])` when you return `NULL` is undefined behavior so you definitely want to make sure the address is valid before you try and access what it points to.

---

Another thing to note is that in the case that you return `NULL`, you function has a memory leak.  You need to move `char* v = new char[len];` to after you decide if you are going to return `NULL`.  You could call `delete [] v;` in the if statement, but that makes the code more brittle.

Comment: From the parameters specified in the question I don't think the intent is to return NULL, but a zero length array.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going on here. Firstly, I would replace that

```
if((start+len) == start)
```

with just

```
if(len == 0) // if(!len) works too
```

And also note that you don't need to take the address of an index, so

```
&c[start] is the same thing as c + start
```

I would read http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/ to make sure you understand that the value being passed is an iterator.

But secondly, your char* v = new char[len] statement is invoking undefined behavior. When you call

```
new char[len];
```

You're merely telling the compiler that you want to give space to a new character array. Remember that std::cout is a function. It is going to detect a char array as a c string. This means that the char array needs to be null terminated. If it's not, you are truly just invoking undefined behavior because you're reading memory on places that have been allocated but not initialized.

When you call

```
if(!r[0])
```

This doesn't really mean anything at all. r[0] is technically initialized, so it is not a nullptr, but it doesn't have any data in it so it is going to evaluate to true with undefined behavior.

Now, if you want to make this more concrete, I would fill the array with zeros

```
char* v = new char[len];
memset(v, 0, len);
```

Now your char is a truly "empty" array.

I think it's just a misunderstanding of what an "empty" array actually means.

Finally, don't listen to the guys who say just use std::vector. They're absolutely right, it's better practice, but it's better to understand how those classes work before you pull out the real power of the standard library. Just saying.